# Showing that complement of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

> The complement of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

I have to solve this problem.

At first, I tried to solve as following: For any 2 disjoint neighborhoods of $\mathbb{R}^2$ \ $\mathbb{Q}^2$, whose union is $\mathbb{R}^2$ \ $\mathbb{Q}^2$,

one of them must be empty.

But I couldn't deduce the last goal.
How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Each pair of elements in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$ can be connected by a path consisting of at most three horizontal or vertical path segments. As an aside, I'm almost certain this question is a duplicate but can't find the previous question - can anyone else?

Comment: [Here's one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356444/topological-proof-to-show-a-complement-set-of-a-set-is-polygonally-connected?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any two point $A,B$ from $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}^2$, join them by a straight line,  draw  perpendicular   bisector of $AB$,Now You start chosing points on the Perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and join to $A$ and $B$ by straightline. How many points you can chose to join $A$ and $B$ like this way?  Do you see your set is path connected?